# How to use js query tags with same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code:

```
<input id="search"/><button onclick="query()">search</button>
<p class="adr">location1</p>
<p class="adr">location2</p>
<p class="adr">location3</p>
<p class="adr">location4</p>
```

for example I enter location1 and  click button then it query by those class = adr and get result is location1, how to do it?

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: Its not clear that what you want. if we want to get result 'location1' by entering 'location1', why? what is the logic of class and get the same result

Comment: What exactly you want to get it

Comment: what does `query()` function does???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to search the location, you can use `filter()` to get all elements with class `adr` and test if their `text()` contains the value of `#search`

`show()` the results.

```js
function query() {
  var search = $("#search").val().trim();        //Get the value of search

  $(".adr").hide().filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().includes(search);
  }).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" /><button onclick="query()">search</button>
<p class="adr">location1</p>
<p class="adr">location2</p>
<p class="adr">location3</p>
<p class="adr">location4</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is exactly is meant, but here is a non-jQuery solution for what I think you are asking for:

```
function query() {
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName("adr");
  var input = document.getElementById("search");
  var content = document.getElementById("content");
  var tag = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i].innerHTML === input.value) {
      tag = els[i];
    }
  }

  // Tag contains the element now
  content.innerHTML = tag.innerHTML;
  return tag;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input id="search"/><button onclick="query()">search</button>
    <p class="adr">location1</p>
    <p class="adr">location2</p>
    <p class="adr">location3</p>
    <p class="adr">location4</p>
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

The element which contain the value searched for is returned by the function, and is also applied to the DOM just to showcase.